# Make consecutive axios post API calls with proper error handling

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, axios

I need to write an API which will call one POST API and pass the data received from it to another POST API and then return the data from second API to the user.

There has to be also proper error handling done so that the API should return error message and not fail when one of the API's does not work

The code that I have tried is as follows

```
listPopularPost: async(req, res) => {
    let requestUrl = process.env.USER_SERVICE_URL+"/api/"+process.env.API_VERSION+'/story-popular';
    try{
        await axios.post(requestUrl, req.body, requestHeader).then((response) => {
            if(response.data.success == true){
                let cmsRequestUrl = process.env.CMS_SERVICE_URL+process.env.API_VERSION+"/story/popular";
                let requestParam = {
                    "request" : req.body,
                    "user_params": response.data.story_ids,
                }
                axios.post(cmsRequestUrl, requestParam,requestHeader).then((response) => {
                    res.status(200).send(response.data);
                }, (error) => {
                    res.status(200).send({'success':false,'code':'request_error','message':'error encountered','data':{'error':error}});
                });
            }
        }, (error) => {
            res.status(200).send(error);
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } 
},
```

But it timesout and does not work. How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using async/await. You could refactor as

```js
listPopularPost: async (req, res) => {
  let requestUrl = process.env.USER_SERVICE_URL + "/api/" + process.env.API_VERSION + '/story-popular';
  try {
    let data = await axios.post(requestUrl, req.body, requestHeader).then((response) => response.data);
    if (data.success) {
      let cmsRequestUrl = process.env.CMS_SERVICE_URL + process.env.API_VERSION + "/story/popular";
      let requestParam = {
        "request": req.body,
        "user_params": data.story_ids,
      }
      data = await axios.post(cmsRequestUrl, requestParam, requestHeader).then((response) => response.data);
      return res.status(200).send(data);
    }

    return res.status(500).send({ 'success': false, 'code': 'request_error', 'message': 'error encountered', 'data': { 'error': new Error("Request wasn't successful") } });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send({ 'success': false, 'code': 'request_error', 'message': 'error encountered', 'data': { 'error': error } });
  }
}
```

or without using async/ await

```js
listPopularPost: (req, res) => {
  let requestUrl = process.env.USER_SERVICE_URL + "/api/" + process.env.API_VERSION + '/story-popular';

  axios.post(requestUrl, req.body, requestHeader).then((response) => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data.success) throw new Error("Request was unsuccessful");

      let cmsRequestUrl = process.env.CMS_SERVICE_URL + process.env.API_VERSION + "/story/popular";
      let requestParam = {
        "request": req.body,
        "user_params": data.story_ids,
      }
      return axios.post(cmsRequestUrl, requestParam, requestHeader);
    })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(data => res.status(200).send(data))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).send({ 'success': false, 'code': 'request_error', 'message': 'error encountered', 'data': { 'error': error } });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this value response.data.story_ids will be passed and not overwritten?

Comment: yes, you're right @SaeeshTendulkar. I just edited it.

Comment: I tried the one using async/await and it jumps to the catch block for some reason

Comment: yes it would jump to the catch block if an error is thrown in any of the promises

Comment: But I tried the individual API's and they both work. How do I debug this?

Comment: what is the error caught in the catch block. The console.log should have printed it out.

Comment: There is no console.log and it returns this response 
{
    "success": false,
    "code": "request_error",
    "message": "error encountered",
    "data": {
        "error": {}
    }
}

Comment: There might be something else going on. You probably want to step through the code with a debugger.